# What is wrong with my implementation of this sentinel value?

Tags: python

**Here is the problem:** This program reads a sequence of floating-point values and computes their average. A value of zero is used as the sentinel. Improve the loop so that the loop is only exited if the user enters the letter Q.

**Here is my code:**

```
total = 0.0
count = 0

# TODO: Fix this program so that it only stops reading numbers
# when the user enters Q.

value = float(input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: "))
while value != "Q" :
   total = total + value
   count = count + 1
   value = float(input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: "))
  
avg = total / count
print(avg)
```

**Here is my error message:**
File "/tmp/codecheck.zUZpqo8apX/computesum.py", line 11, in 
value = float(input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Q'

Comment: Why not convert the input to a float *after* you test if it equals `'Q'`? Your `float()` is too soon.

Comment: I don't follow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your code:

```py
value = float(input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: "))
```

If you want to handle a non-float value like `Q`, you should be treating it as a *string* at that point, not immediately trying to convert it to a `float` (which will fail for `Q`, as you've discoverd).

In other words, something like:

```py
value = input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: ")
while value != "Q" :
    total = total + float(value)
    count = count + 1
    value = input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: ")
```

---

That will still cause problems if you enter a value that is neither `Q` *nor* a valid `float` but you could handle this by catching an exception and adjusting behaviour:

```py
value = input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: ")
while value != "Q" :
    try:
        total = total + float(value)
        count = count + 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid float value, try again.")
    value = input("Enter a real value or Q to quit: ")
```

If the `float()` call fails in that case, neither `total` nor `count` will be updated and the `except` block will be executed, letting the user know there was a problem.

---

The only other thing I'll mention is that you should think about the case where the *first* thing you do is enter `Q`. In that case, `count` will still be set to zero so you probably *don't* want to divide by it. Instead, you could do something like:

```py
if count == 0:
    print("No values entered therefore no average.")
else:
    avg = total / count
    print(avg)
```

Comment: Thank you. We have not learned about except yet, but the first answer was the one that worked. Thank you for your assistance. One of the most important things this book has taught me is how to ask for help. Its crazy when you see people improve on the code written in your college text book and you start to realize that even college professors make mistakes.

Comment: @hunt67241 What mistakes by professors are you talking about?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy a professor wrote that book and wrote the majority of the code for that problem. The only thing I changed was the while value != 0 to while value != "Q", paxdiablo pointed out that the code would still crash if a string value of anything but "Q" was entered. So, in essence the code was not perfect. It was still kind of buggy and I feel like I learned more from paxdiablo about the problem than the professors that authored Pyhon For Everyone. I guess I should rephrase that statement to "I guess code can always be improved, no matter how much experience you have."

Comment: @hunt67241 the thing is the code used to work okay until the moment you've made that change(it wasnt buggy then, since 0 is valid `float`). So in essence, you **introduced** the bug.

Comment: Thats a good point... I didn't think about that. The code was meant to be buggy so if they added the exception in the first.

Comment: Well, you could argue the code was buggy in a *different* way, in that entering `0` as the first value (zero was the original sentinel) would result in a divide-by-zero :-)